# Can I make the aws ecs run-task command block until the task is complete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-fargate

I'm trying to AWS-ize some batch processes that currently run as dockerized task on company internal servers.

I can start my process with a command like this:

```
aws ecs run-task --task-definition fv-scf-0 --cluster fv-sal --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[subnet-x,subnet-y],securityGroups=[sg-z]}" --launch-type FARGATE --started-by xxxyyy
```

This immediately launches the batch, and then exits. But can I modify this so that the command blocks until the task has finished executing? If I can do that, then I can use a call to a fargate task as a drop-in replacement for my current generation of processes running on a local server.

Comment: No, you can't, not using that command alone. But you get the taskArn back and can then combine it with a second CLI call, this time to `aws ecs wait tasks-stopped` which waits / blocks until a task is finished.

Comment: One limit of the `ecs wait` command is that it only waits for 600 seconds. However, it's not difficult to write a Python script that will start a job and then wait for it to complete.